# Graph $[0,\infty) \Rightarrow (0,1]$ Less Severe than $e^{-x}$

Tags: graphing-functions

I want a graph that goes from $[0, \infty) \Rightarrow (0, 1]$ a bit like $e^{-x}$, but less severe. By that I mean I do not want all the action around $0$.

The $y$ axis must start at $1$ and decay to, but not reach $0$.

I could obviously scale the $x$-axis, but it is still severe with most movement around $0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "action around 0?"

Comment: With the same idea as @Mithrandir's answer, but simple and algebraic, why not try $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+ax^2}$, or, for that matter, $\dfrac{1}{1+ax}$. With the positive $a$ close to $0$ you can have as flat a negative slope as you want. Then again, you can even try $\dfrac{1}{1+a \log(x+1)}$, or use log log ..., but that brings us back in transcendental territory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(x)=-\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan(ax)+1$

The rate of convergence can be controlled with parameter $a$. In general, this function will converge to $0$ much slower than $e^{-x}$, since the derivative of $\arctan$ is $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. The $-\frac{2}{\pi}$ and $+1$ ensure that the graph meets your stipulated conditions.

[image]

Edit: Start by thinking of functions with horizontal asymptotes which converge more slowly then the exponential function. Then, adjust so they meet the parameters you're looking for. Another example would be $y=\frac{1}{x}$. Adjusting to meet your requirements: $f(x)=\frac{1}{ax+1}$. Choose $a\in(0,1)$ as desired.

Comment: Can you please explain what led you to this/you came across this graph earlier?

Comment: @PCMSE edited to address this